# Kept getting redirected to login page after keying login details correctly

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-authentication

can someone help me? Even though I have keyed in the correct credentials, I kept getting redirected back to the login page instead of the index page. Everything appears to be working fine, am unable to find the root cause of the problem.

My view code

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
            print('user:', user)
            print(password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                print('1')
                return redirect('app:index')
            else:
                print('2')
                return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid email or password.'})
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    print('3')
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Terminal Output

```
3
1
3
```

Edit: Included my index page view

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

2nd Edit: Included my urls.py

```
# from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from django.views.static import serve
from . import views
from .views import GenerateQRCodeView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'app'
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
urlpatterns = [

    path(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    path("", views.login_view, name="login_view"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login_view"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("index", views.index, name="index"),
    path("users", views.users, name="users"),
    path("log", views.log, name="log"),
    path("logout", views.userlogout, name="logout"),
    path('password_reset/', views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('qr_code/', GenerateQRCodeView.as_view(), name='generate-qr-code'),
    path('user_edit/', views.user_edit, name="user_edit")
    #path('sms/', SendSMS.as_view(), name='send_sms'),
]
```

Comment: show the index page's view

Comment: i believe you don't need to pass request as an authenticate() argument

Comment: @rolandist_scim `request` is an optional argument, it's totally upto you whether to pass or not. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) at the end of docs.

Comment: can you share `urls.py`?

Comment: Hello it seems that you have defined `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`  to login page in `settings.py` file, kindly check it. It must be set to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/index/'` or simply you can remove it since you are manually redirecting the user after login.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Hi, I have removed but unfortunately it does not appear to be working. I still get redirected to the login page.

Comment: Can you please also remove `None` from `LoginForm(request.POST or None)` since you are already defining an empty `LoginForm()` in `else` condition which is for `GET` request, so it should only be `LoginForm(request.POST`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey removed, still not working

Comment: Listen share the GitHub repo :) if possible.

Comment: I am assuming you've already defined `USERNAME_FIELD = "email"` in the model.